# What has the best performance for async calls on iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, performance, grand-central-dispatch

I search for a better performance for asynchronous calls on iOS if there's a performance issue in a threaded call and I want to optimize it.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(switch) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay inModes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
```

has a GCD call like:

```
dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC); dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
[self switch];
});
```

a better performance? Or anybody an idea? I guess a timer would only be more glue...

Comment: did you try to create a queue with a higher priority level ?

Comment: Please define your *fast* (your goal) more clearly in this context. In most cases a method call cost ignorable, and other stuffs affect more in threaded code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a performance problem in your app, it's not here. There are two possibilities:

1. You are making vast numbers of these calls in which case the performance of the dispatch mechanism is actually a problem. In that case, rework your application logic so that you don't need to make so many calls!
2. You are not making that many calls, in which case the performance of the dispatch is simply a non-issue compared to whatever it is in your code that is the real problem.

Why do you think you have a performance problem here?

Answer (score 0):

```
mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(callAfteroneSecond) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:mytimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

or

```
  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(Fav_function) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: And why would this be a better performance than lets say the GCD solution?